# gsap scrolltrigger animation pinspacing a false

Tags: gsap, scrolltrigger

I would like to have the same effect but with pinSpacing: false,
the panel must freeze and run the internal animation and then go to the next one.

```
ScrollTrigger.create({
    trigger: panel,
    start: "top top",
    pin: true,
    end: "bottom top",
    pinSpacing: true, // pin spacing FALSE
    markers: true,
   id: `panel-${i}`
});
```

example
https://codepen.io/aldozumaran/pen/QWaKobZ